# Running jar files in subdirectories

Tags: java, bash

I've looked throughout stack overflow for a good answer to this, but no solution seems to work well.

I have a directory A, and in directory A, there is a subdirectory B. 
In Subdirectory B there is a jar file, let us call it start.jar (as well as a lib file in that directory). How would I run that jar file from directory A without ever cd'ing into subdirectory B.

I'm guessing you can do it with a -cp instruction, but I'm not sure how that would work.

-- I made a mistake by saying remote as people pointed out. I just meant a subdirectory. 
The thing is, when I run the jar file in subdirectory B, it runs. However, when I do java -jar Path/To/B/start.jar from directory A, it errors out. I was wondering how to solve this issue.

Edit: 
So I think I was unclear about my problem. Sorry about that, I will clear it out. 
I am running a solr_instance.

I have directory "A" which is solr_instance.

Within solr_instance, there is a folder, solr_instance/solr-4.6.1/example which has a start.jar file and a lib folder (as well as other files of course).

When I run java -jar solr_instance/solr-4.6.1/example.start.jar I get the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in start.config or command line.
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

When I run it within the subdirectory, it works. I was wondering why that is the case, and if so, is there a way of actually doing it (without cd'ing into it).

Sorry if I was somewhat unclear before!

Comment: Where does the `remote part ` come in here?

Comment: @sjsam: I suspect that the OP has misunderstood the term "remote", and believes that the jar-file is "remote" because it's not in the current directory.

Comment: @ruakh : Well, could be the case. :)

Comment: If you're doing `java -jar Path/To/B/start.jar` and it "errors out", the jar may be looking for that library you mentioned in the working directory. If that's the case, it's probably easiest to just `cd` to it. Of course, this is all speculation without having read your error message (it may be helpful if you post it).

Answer (score 1):

In directory `A` try:

```
java -jar B/start.jar
```

Comment: Nice ++, This should do for the requirement as mentioned in the question. but I'm a bit confused as the op has mentioned `remote` in the title. So let's wait for an update ++

Answer (score 1):

Run/Access `start.jar` From A without ever `cd`ing to `B` would be

```
user@hostname:~some/path/to/A$ java -jar ./B/start.jar #more explicit
```

or

```
user@hostname:~some/path/to/A$ java -jar B/start.jar # This will look local B
```